# C language - Read specific data from text file

Tags: c, text, file-io

I'm studying file I/O.
I have a trouble in reading specific data.

text file :

```
index (x,y)

 1     2,3   1,5   8,2

 2     4,4

 3     0,1   9,4

 4
```

The number of `(x,y)` can be changed.

I read only numbers with following code:

while (1){

```
    getNum = fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);

    if (getNum == EOF)

        break;

    else if (getNum < 1)

        fscanf(fp, "%*[^0-9]");

    else

        printf("%d\t", num);

    }
```

How can I split index, x, y?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far or make your question more specific. As it is, your question is unclear. What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I read data that way.. but I cannot split each element.. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Read the file line by line
- Split a single line with space " " as delimiter into fields
- starting at the second field (if present): split each field using comma "," as delimiter
- convert each subfield from string to integer